# Movement and Rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm currently learning Unity 3D but I stuck on  a problem.
So Iv'e done this code that the player moves with WASD keys. The movement works fine.
I tried to aply some rotation, that way the player can turn back or move to different positions.
But the problem is, I put the rotarion and the player turns but when he does he swap W for S, so basically if I turn back, when I press W to go forward he go backward and when I press S instead of going Backward he goes Forward.
I don't to make a lot of changes in my code because I think it's very "basic" right now and easy to understand. So if someone can explain what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


//[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerMov : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Player mov speed
    float MovSpeed = 10f;

    //Player jump, jumpforce, check if is on the ground and rb(rigidbody component)
    public Vector3 jump;
    public float jumpForce = 2.0f;
    public bool isGrounded;
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float TurnSpeed = 100f;
   
    

  



    void Start()
    {
        
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }




    void Update()
    {
       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.position -= Vector3.forward * MovSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            //transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * MovSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        }

       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {

            transform.position -= Vector3.left * MovSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            

        }

       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {

            transform.position -= Vector3.back * MovSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            //transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * MovSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        }

       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {

            transform.position -= Vector3.right * MovSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {

            rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            isGrounded = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the Translate method? Please see its documentation. You can define a which space you want the transform to move in (global or local)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

As a side note: why check for each separate key? Using `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` and `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` vertical would be simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much erdostamasa! It works perfectly. You helped me a lot and now I understand so much more and how wrong I was doing things! Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @FernandoSilva Glad I could help! Could you upvote the question if it solved your problem?